# Produce CodeIgniter Active Record from MySQL query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have this mysql query and I am very new to CodeIgniter, How can I make this an active record query?

```
SELECT 
    chp_id, 
    chp_destination, 
    cde_name, 
    chp_year, 
    chp_from, 
    chp_to, 
    chp_budget_price_high, 
    chp_medium_price_high, 
    chp_luxury_price_high,
    chp_budget_price_low, 
    chp_medium_price_low, 
    chp_luxury_price_low, 
    chp_timestamp,
    chp_comment
FROM crm_hotel_price
LEFT JOIN crm_destinations ON cde_id = chp_destination
WHERE chp_id IN 
    (
        SELECT MAX( chp_id )
        FROM crm_hotel_price
        GROUP BY chp_destination, chp_year
    )
ORDER BY 
    chp_id
```

Comment: that is what I tried, and found out that mysql subquery is not yet supported by CodeIgniter's active record..Is there a way other way on how to make this with CI's active record?

Comment: Have a look at this one -> http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html . You can do something like `$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");` and then to get the result `$query->result()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes subquery is not yet supported by active record and you can't extend the class easily.  So you want to do something like this (not tested)

```
$this->db->select('chp_id')
    ->select('chp_destination')
    ->select('cde_name')
    ->select('chp_year')
    ->select('chp_from')
    ->select('chp_to')
    ->select('chp_budget_price_high')
    ->select('chp_medium_price_high')
    ->select('chp_luxury_price_high')
    ->select('chp_budget_price_low')
    ->select('chp_medium_price_low')
    ->select('chp_luxury_price_low')
    ->select('chp_timestamp')
    ->select('chp_comment')
->from('crm_hotel_price')
->join('crm_destinations', 'cde_id = chp_destination', 'left')
->where('chp_id IN (SELECT MAX( chp_id ) FROM crm_hotel_price GROUP BY chp_destination, chp_year)')
->order_by('chp_id');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: I think your code ->order_by('ORDER BY chp_id'); should be like this ->order_by('chp_id');